# Why WP_Query('showposts=5') shows only 1 post?

Tags: posts, php, wp-query, loop, query-posts

I am trying to do a simple query to get the latest 5 posts into an unordered list, but this is only showing 1 result even though I have several posts. I even did an offset, but it shows the next post yet still 1 result. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ul>
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query('showposts=5'); ?>
    <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <p><?php the_content_limit(250); ?></p>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile;?>
</ul>
```

Comment: i am new in this filed i want to use this code in my website,but i don't know where i use this code in my website. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: To post questions please don't use the answers.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: For context the Answer by @sammy was converted to a comment, I've preserved the responses for sammys benefit, ps: welcome to the community :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_content_limit` does not exist in WordPress. You probably want something like [`the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt).

What's likely happening is your loop is working fine, but the call to an undefined function causes the program to error out, making it appear the the loop is not working. Look at the rendered HTML: you'll probably see a single, opening `<li>` tag, the link and an opening paragraph tag.

`showposts` is also deprecated. Take a look [in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters): dropped in 2.1

Try this:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 5,
));

while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </li>
<?php endwhile;
```

Comment: That's what happens when you cut and paste from the web. Thanks for the update! It works!!

Answer (score -2):

The default syntax for post_per_page is-

```
<?php
      $query = new WP_Query
      (array(
                 'posts_per_page'   => 5,
             )
       );

       while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
      <li>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
          <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
     </li>
<?php endwhile;
```

Comment: `showposts` was dropped in favor of `posts_per_page`. Please read the accepted answer

Comment: okay ..but showposts also worked in my case.

Comment: Yes, it does, but it is depreciated it might get removed in future which will break your site

Comment: Please reread my comment, **do not use `showposts`**, it is **depreciated**